# Can I have a pop up box in R shiny display the results of a R markdown file?

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to have a pop up box display a R markdown file? I specifically need the pop up box to display the results from a R markdown file. I tried the way below, but the dialogue box won't display the plot of the random normal variables.

Sample code for the dialogue box with the R markdown file:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$show, {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Important message",
        includeMarkdown("Test.Rmd"),
        easyClose = TRUE
      ))
    })
  }
)
```

Markdown code:

```
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---
```

R:

```
plot(rnorm(10,0,1))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to take a slightly different approach to do this. If you `render` the `.Rmd` then you can present it in the `modalDialog` using `renderUI`.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
  ),      
  server = function(input, output) {

    md_out <- rmarkdown::render("Test.Rmd")

    observeEvent(input$show, {

      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Important message",
        renderUI(HTML(readLines(md_out))),
        easyClose = TRUE
      ))

    })
})
```

[image]

> **N.B.** You can always make the `.Rmd` render step reactive based on another input, the dialog could then be dynamic.